# Как декодировать json строку из ответа

Tags: php, json

Сервер присылает строку такого типа:

```
    [
    {
        "available": false,
        "occasional": true,
        "id": 101033014307,
        "ticket_scope": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-04-26T21:35:05Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-26T21:35:05Z",
        "last_active_at": null,
        "available_since": null,
        "type": "support_agent",
        "contact": {
            "active": false,
            "email": "custserv@freshdesk.com",
            "job_title": null,
            "language": "en",
            "last_login_at": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "name": "Customer Service",
            "phone": null,
            "time_zone": "Casablanca",
            "created_at": "2022-04-26T21:35:05Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-26T21:35:05Z"
        },
        "signature": null
    },
    {
        "available": false,
        "occasional": false,
        "id": 101033014303,
        "ticket_scope": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-04-26T21:35:00Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-27T08:02:23Z",
        "last_active_at": "2022-04-27T08:02:23Z",
        "available_since": null,
        "type": "support_agent",
        "contact": {
            "active": true,
            "email": "werdsfsdfs@gmail.com",
            "job_title": null,
            "language": "en",
            "last_login_at": "2022-04-27T08:01:37Z",
            "mobile": null,
            "name": "Senh",
            "phone": "12345678",
            "time_zone": "Casablanca",
            "created_at": "2022-04-26T21:35:00Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-27T08:02:20Z"
        },
        "signature": null
    },
    {
        "available": false,
        "occasional": true,
        "id": 101033173099,
        "ticket_scope": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-04-27T09:48:16Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-27T09:48:16Z",
        "last_active_at": null,
        "available_since": null,
        "type": "support_agent",
        "contact": {
            "active": false,
            "email": "superman@freshdesk.com",
            "job_title": null,
            "language": "en",
            "last_login_at": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "name": "Super man",
            "phone": null,
            "time_zone": "Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
            "created_at": "2022-04-27T09:48:16Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-27T09:48:16Z"
        },
        "signature": "<div dir=\"ltr\"><p><br></p>\n</div>"
    }
]
```

Как этот ответ переобразовать в объект или массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = json_decode($string, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Первая страница гугла (https://google.com), вот [Пруф](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20json%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%20php&oq=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20json%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%20php&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3175j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (К слову, я просто скопировал тайтл вопроса, и добавил нужный язык, т.е `php`) Если необходимо - сделаю подобную инструкцию и для других поисковых систем, так что обращайтесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же, для этого прекрасного языка есть документация, вот [Ссылка](https://www.php.net/docs.php), а вот [пруф](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20php%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%3F&oq=%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20php%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160j33i160i395l3.11523j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), что я не вру.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я делал это с ошибкой. Я пытался декодировать без флага "true". Сюда же обращаюсь уже когда сам не могу ничего найти